# Save Authentication in browser's local storage

Tags: node.js, express, local-storage, ejs

I'm using Node Express with EJS. I have build a user Authentication using JWT and storing generated Token in Cookies with following code

```
res.cookie('authorization', token, {maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000});
```

Same at the time of verification I can very easily read it from cookies

```
req.cookies['authorization'];
```

Using this method I don't have to do any authentication related code at frontend. But I read it somewhere that best practice is to store it in browser's local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("authorization", "..object..");
```

This code seems to be frontend code. Which means I have to send my token to frontend and then save it to localStorage.

Can this is done without sending token to frontend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working fine with cookies.  To use local storage you need to send to token back to the front end(upon verification)  and attach it on every subsequent request.   local storage can be accessed by the javascript and is vulnerable to xss attacks. 
 Better use cookies with HTTPOnly flag.